# Is the output of GCOV stored anywhere?

Tags: gcov

Is the output, as shown below,

```
File 'printtokens.c'
Lines executed:47.18% of 195
Branches executed:65.14% of 109
Taken at least once:35.78% of 109
Calls executed:33.33% of 81
printtokens.c:creating 'printtokens.c.gcov'
```

generated by GCOV stored somewhere? If not, how can we store it?

Answer (score 1):

GCOV calculates that from the information in the *.gcda files, but if you want to keep that summary around the easiest thing to do is

```
gcov printtokens.c > printtokens.c.summary
```

If you want to see that information together with the line coverage, you could look at [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php), which uses gcov to generate HTML files with the line coverage and summary coverage information.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Ankur.

You should use it in this way:

From the directory in which .gcno and .gcda are located, write the command:

**lcov -c -d . -o fileName.info**

And then, to generate a HTML report:

**genhtml fileName.info**

It is the proper way to view the results.